# how to disable adcash popup promotion in my web server?

Tags: popup

I my website http://example.com.au, I don't know how adcash is activated, whenever I am trying to open a link from the home page, adcash popup is opening automatically. I believe this is not a issue in my browser, as I am only facing this issue on particularly this website, also I have tested the issue from other pcs, which is also opening the same popups. Please help me to block this spam.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yet I don't know how to remove it but there are some information that may be usefull:

1. This is problem not only on Windows, but Mac and Linux as well (and smart-phones too).
2. The virus may be on your router.
3. Don't install programs that proposed to you from Google, Bing etc. in order to remove the virus (install only well know programs and read help from well know cites). The thing is that the virus probably may change output of search engines, and you may install a real virus on your computer (most of such "adcash antivirus" programs ask you to run under administrator 
   privileges)

(from https://askubuntu.com/questions/626170/adcash-removal-assistance-needed)